# Pegar item contido em um item da uma ListView ao clicar no item

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

Minha situação é a seguinte, minha listView carrega os itens em um xml que criei para cada item da listVIew[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na hora listagem fica assim:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O que eu quero fazer é, ao clicar, pegar esses itens circulados em vermelho, seja pelo Id, ou da forma que for, e enviar para outra activite, mas até agora eu consegui no máximo pegar o Id de cada item da listView.

Método para carregar os dados do banco:

```
        public Cursor loadData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db =  this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =   db.query(TableEstructure.Table.TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Método para carregar os dados na listView:

```
    public void loadRegisters(){

    db = new DataBase(MainActivity.this);
    String[] from = {
            TableEstructure.Table.COLUMN_ID,
            TableEstructure.Table.COLUMN_DATE,
            TableEstructure.Table.COLUMN_STATE,
            TableEstructure.Table.COLUMN_CUTED_TREES,
            TableEstructure.Table.COLUMN_VOLUME_CUTED_TREES};

    int[]to = {R.id.txtId,
            R.id.textState,
            R.id.textDate,
            R.id.textCutedTrees,
            R.id.txtVolCutTree};
    SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter =  new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.item_list,db.loadData(),from,to);

    list.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
}
```

Alguém tem a solução para o meu problema? 
gratíssimo desde já!

Comment: Mudança de planos! Ao invés de tentar pegar os itens do ItemListView no click, passei o Id do item clicado e na activitie seguinte fiz uma consulta através dele e usei os dados.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, blza?!

Voce poderia pegar os dados de acordo com a posição do item clicado:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        //aqui vc irá fazer a acao com o click pegando uma posicao da sua lista
        mId = mlista[position].getId();
    }
});
```